# резиновые блоки

Tags: css

Есть 4 `div` в ряд, каждый из которых имеет `width=25%` от родителя. Стандартное поведение при уменьшении окна браузера - один из блоков падает в следующий ряд, а те 3, что остались, не меняют свою ширину (т.е остается пустой пробел от блока, что сместился). Как можно сделать так, чтобы при смещении крайнего блока в новый ряд те 3 оставшихся растягивались по всей ширине родителя? Тут вроде бы медиа запрос нужен, но я без понятия как ним управлять.

```css
.basket_container{    
  display:block;    
}


.basket_border {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  float:left;  
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 30px 8px 10px 10px;
  position:relative;  
  width:25%;
}


.basket_plus{
  text-align: center;
  color: #f38104;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: -5px;    
}

.basket_minus{    
  font-size: 1.8em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;    
  right: 56px;   
}

.basket_number{
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 20px;    
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 2px -2px #bbb,1px 1px 1px 1px #bbb;
}

.selected_basket_product{
  bottom: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}

.basket_counter{
  position:absolute;    
}

.basket_price_block{
  margin-top:20px; 
  min-width:220px;   
}

#rectangle {
  width: 110px;
  height: 39px;
  background: #FFEBCD;    
  float:left;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
}

#basket_buy{    
  float:left;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#basket_buy_price{
  margin: 9px;
  text-align: center;
}

.basket_button_block{
  float: right;
}

.basket_contact_details{
  width: 36px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #f38104;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 0 2px 0; 
  position:absolute;
  left:-45px;    
}

.basket_headline{    
  padding: 7px 0px 6px 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #afafaf;
  font-weight: bold;
  width:88%;
}


.basket_block_info{
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  outline: none;
  width: 273px;
}

.basket_picture img{    
  width: 100px;
}

.basket_picture {
  width:16%;
  height:115px;
}
.basket_product_description{
  width:39%;    
}

.basket_product_joke{    
  font-weight:bold;
  width:19%   
}

.basket_product_price{   
  font-weight:bold; 
  min-width:150px;
}

#basket_hidden_products{
  margin: 15px 0px;   
  width:680px;
}

.basket_data{
  margin: 15px 0px;
}
#basket_total_text{
  text-align: center;
  margin:10px;
  padding:5px 0;
  margin-top:10px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.basket_total_description{
  width:52%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.basket_total_price{     
  background: #FFDAB9;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 30px;   
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  outline:none;
  font-family: GothicR;
}

.lower_basket_table{
  width:680px;  
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

.headline_block{
  position:relative;    
}

.basket_total_joke{
  width:17%;
  font-weight:bold;
  display:inline-block;
}

#basket_hidden_info{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="basket_container">    
  <div class="basket_border selected_product_border_basket">            
    <div class="selected_product_image">
      <img src="images/product/Без имени-1.jpg" alt="" />                           
    </div>                 
    <div class="basket_close">
      <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="">            
      <div class="basket_description"> product description </div>
    </div>                
    <div class="basket_price_block">                
      <img src="images/personal_cabinet/basket1.png" class="basket_price_image" alt="" />
      <div class="basket_price">
        <span  class="product_price" data-unitprice="4500">4500</span>
        <span >USD</span>                        
      </div>
      <div class="selected_basket_product">                    
        <span class="basket_minus"> - </span>
        <input class="basket_number" name="basket_number" value="1" />
        <span class="basket_plus"> + </span>                                        
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>                               
    </div>                                 
  </div>    
  <div class="basket_border selected_product_border_basket">            
    <div class="selected_product_image">
      <img src="images/product/Без имени-2.jpg" alt="" />                           
    </div>                 
    <div class="basket_close">
      <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="">            
      <div class="basket_description"> product description </div>
    </div>                
    <div class="basket_price_block">                
      <img src="images/personal_cabinet/basket1.png" class="basket_price_image" alt="" />
      <div class="basket_price">
        <span  class="product_price" data-unitprice="4500">4500</span>
        <span >USD</span>                        
      </div>
      <div class="selected_basket_product">                    
        <span class="basket_minus"> - </span>
        <input class="basket_number" name="basket_number" value="1" />
        <span class="basket_plus"> + </span>                                        
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>                               
    </div>                                 
  </div>      
  <div class="basket_border selected_product_border_basket">            
    <div class="selected_product_image">
      <img src="images/product/Без имени-3.jpg" alt="" />                           
    </div>                 
    <div class="basket_close">
      <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="">            
      <div class="basket_description"> product description </div>
    </div>                
    <div class="basket_price_block">                
      <img src="images/personal_cabinet/basket1.png" class="basket_price_image" alt="" />
      <div class="basket_price">
        <span  class="product_price" data-unitprice="4500">4500</span>
        <span >USD</span>                        
      </div>
      <div class="selected_basket_product">                    
        <span class="basket_minus"> - </span>
        <input class="basket_number" name="basket_number" value="1" />
        <span class="basket_plus"> + </span>                                        
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>                               
    </div>                                 
  </div>    
  <div class="basket_border selected_product_border_basket">            
    <div class="selected_product_image">
      <img src="images/product/Без имени-4.jpg" alt="" />                           
    </div>                 
    <div class="basket_close">
      <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="">            
      <div class="basket_description"> product description </div>
    </div>                
    <div class="basket_price_block">                
      <img src="images/personal_cabinet/basket1.png" class="basket_price_image" alt="" />
      <div class="basket_price">
        <span  class="product_price" data-unitprice="4500">4500</span>
        <span >USD</span>                        
      </div>
      <div class="selected_basket_product">                    
        <span class="basket_minus"> - </span>
        <input class="basket_number" name="basket_number" value="1" />
        <span class="basket_plus"> + </span>                                        
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>                               
    </div>                                 
  </div>    
  <div class="clear"></div>    
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте часть вашей разметки чтобы увидеть проблему!

Comment: обновил вопрос с разметкой

Comment: Хорошо, вижу 4 блока в ряд, но у них нет `width=25%`

Comment: убрал из `basket_border` т.к. при уменьшении разрешения, контент налазит внутри блока

Comment: Уже лучше, вам нужно при уменьшении разрешения только последний растянуть или лучше сделать сначала 4 в рад, далее 2 и в конце 1?

Comment: сначало 4 в ряд, при уменьшении разрешения, 4й падает вниз, а 3 что остались растягиваются на всю ширину

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34536/discussion-between-igor-tkachuk-and-dirk).

Comment: ваще не врубаюсь о чем вы, но штуки которые вы творите, нравятся мне) крутые ребята)

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так получается. В конце медиа запрос, если ширина будет меньше `905px` (исправите на свое значение), тогда последний блок упадет вниз и станет `100%`, а предыдущие останутся на месте, но растянутся на всю ширину, каждый по `33.33%`.

```css
.basket_container{    
  display:block;    
}


.basket_border {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  float:left;  
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 30px 8px 10px 10px;
  position:relative;  
  width:25%;
}


.basket_plus{
  text-align: center;
  color: #f38104;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: -5px;    
}

.basket_minus{    
  font-size: 1.8em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;    
  right: 56px;   
}

.basket_number{
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 20px;    
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 2px -2px #bbb,1px 1px 1px 1px #bbb;
}

.selected_basket_product{
  bottom: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}

.basket_counter{
  position:absolute;    
}

.basket_price_block{
  margin-top:20px; 
  min-width:220px;   
}

#rectangle {
  width: 110px;
  height: 39px;
  background: #FFEBCD;    
  float:left;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
}

#basket_buy{    
  float:left;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#basket_buy_price{
  margin: 9px;
  text-align: center;
}

.basket_button_block{
  float: right;
}

.basket_contact_details{
  width: 36px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #f38104;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 0 2px 0; 
  position:absolute;
  left:-45px;    
}

.basket_headline{    
  padding: 7px 0px 6px 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #afafaf;
  font-weight: bold;
  width:88%;
}


.basket_block_info{
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  outline: none;
  width: 273px;
}

.basket_picture img{    
  width: 100px;
}

.basket_picture {
  width:16%;
  height:115px;
}
.basket_product_description{
  width:39%;    
}

.basket_product_joke{    
  font-weight:bold;
  width:19%   
}

.basket_product_price{   
  font-weight:bold; 
  min-width:150px;
}

#basket_hidden_products{
  margin: 15px 0px;   
  width:680px;
}

.basket_data{
  margin: 15px 0px;
}
#basket_total_text{
  text-align: center;
  margin:10px;
  padding:5px 0;
  margin-top:10px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.basket_total_description{
  width:52%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.basket_total_price{     
  background: #FFDAB9;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 30px;   
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  outline:none;
  font-family: GothicR;
}

.lower_basket_table{
  width:680px;  
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

.headline_block{
  position:relative;    
}

.basket_total_joke{
  width:17%;
  font-weight:bold;
  display:inline-block;
}

#basket_hidden_info{
  display:none;
}

@media (max-width: 905px) {
  .basket_border:not(:nth-child(4)) {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .basket_border:nth-child(4) {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="basket_container">    
  <div class="basket_border selected_product_border_basket">            
    <div class="selected_product_image">
      <img src="images/product/Без имени-1.jpg" alt="" />                           
    </div>                 
    <div class="basket_close">
      <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="">            
      <div class="basket_description"> product description </div>
    </div>                
    <div class="basket_price_block">                
      <img src="images/personal_cabinet/basket1.png" class="basket_price_image" alt="" />
      <div class="basket_price">
        <span  class="product_price" data-unitprice="4500">4500</span>
        <span >USD</span>                        
      </div>
      <div class="selected_basket_product">                    
        <span class="basket_minus"> - </span>
        <input class="basket_number" name="basket_number" value="1" />
        <span class="basket_plus"> + </span>                                        
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>                               
    </div>                                 
  </div>    
  <div class="basket_border selected_product_border_basket">            
    <div class="selected_product_image">
      <img src="images/product/Без имени-2.jpg" alt="" />                           
    </div>                 
    <div class="basket_close">
      <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="">            
      <div class="basket_description"> product description </div>
    </div>                
    <div class="basket_price_block">                
      <img src="images/personal_cabinet/basket1.png" class="basket_price_image" alt="" />
      <div class="basket_price">
        <span  class="product_price" data-unitprice="4500">4500</span>
        <span >USD</span>                        
      </div>
      <div class="selected_basket_product">                    
        <span class="basket_minus"> - </span>
        <input class="basket_number" name="basket_number" value="1" />
        <span class="basket_plus"> + </span>                                        
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>                               
    </div>                                 
  </div>      
  <div class="basket_border selected_product_border_basket">            
    <div class="selected_product_image">
      <img src="images/product/Без имени-3.jpg" alt="" />                           
    </div>                 
    <div class="basket_close">
      <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="">            
      <div class="basket_description"> product description </div>
    </div>                
    <div class="basket_price_block">                
      <img src="images/personal_cabinet/basket1.png" class="basket_price_image" alt="" />
      <div class="basket_price">
        <span  class="product_price" data-unitprice="4500">4500</span>
        <span >USD</span>                        
      </div>
      <div class="selected_basket_product">                    
        <span class="basket_minus"> - </span>
        <input class="basket_number" name="basket_number" value="1" />
        <span class="basket_plus"> + </span>                                        
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>                               
    </div>                                 
  </div>    
  <div class="basket_border selected_product_border_basket">            
    <div class="selected_product_image">
      <img src="images/product/Без имени-4.jpg" alt="" />                           
    </div>                 
    <div class="basket_close">
      <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="">            
      <div class="basket_description"> product description </div>
    </div>                
    <div class="basket_price_block">                
      <img src="images/personal_cabinet/basket1.png" class="basket_price_image" alt="" />
      <div class="basket_price">
        <span  class="product_price" data-unitprice="4500">4500</span>
        <span >USD</span>                        
      </div>
      <div class="selected_basket_product">                    
        <span class="basket_minus"> - </span>
        <input class="basket_number" name="basket_number" value="1" />
        <span class="basket_plus"> + </span>                                        
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>                               
    </div>                                 
  </div>    
  <div class="clear"></div>    
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: а если просто растягивать оставшийся блоки на 33% ( если добавить еще пару таких "рядов" то все шахматной доской получсется)

Comment: @dirk, что вы хотите получить в итоге? я просто не совсем понимаю.

Comment: ну допустим я добавлю блоков , и в итоге получится допустим несколько рядов , в каждом из которых 4 блока. Нужно просто что бы при уменьшении экрана , если все 4 блока не влазят в один ряд, то сам ряд уже был не из 4х блоков а из 3х

Answer (score 1):

[Вот так](https://jsfiddle.net/jdwpjph8/) это элементарно делается flex'ами:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  background: #495780;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #fff;
}

.fbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.one-four{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 20%;
  min-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fbox">
<div class="one-four">1</div>
  <div class="one-four">2</div>
    <div class="one-four">3</div>
      <div class="one-four">4</div>
  
</div>
```